# How to check if all the elements in a list is in another list while skipping unncessary elements

Tags: python

I have a list `['4H', '5D', 'AC', '7H']` and `[H, D]`.
How do I check if the first index [1] of all elements are in the second list while skipping all the elemtns that starts with 'A'.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code you have tried in order to allow people to help you with your code.

Comment: what is your expected output, do you want to print something, or return something?

Comment: Maybe `all(e[1] in ['H', 'D'] for e in ['4H', '5D', 'AC', '7H'] if e[0] != 'A')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python 3.9+ (`startswith()` method) :

```
lst1 = ['4H', '5D', 'AC', '7H', '7J']
lst2 = ['H', 'D']

for item in lst1:
    if not item.startswith('A') and item[1] in lst2:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this

```py
lst1 = ['4H', '5D', 'AC', '7H']
lst2 = ["H", "D"]

for item in lst1:
    indexed = item[0]
    if indexed != "A":
        if indexed in lst2:
            print(f"{indexed} Found in lst2")
```

Comment: The condition `if indexed != "A":` should be `if item[0] != "A":`.  Since the question states "skipping all the elemtns that starts with 'A'.".

Comment: @schilli Oh, yes.